# Remove Specific Search-Suggestion in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-history, search-suggestion

### Firefox 95.0

1. I want to remove a specific suggestion only.
2. I have removed the related entry from my firefox history already.
3. I have restarted firefox.
4. The suggestion won't cease to exist.

---

1. I have disabled all history related search suggestions.
2. I have restarted firefox.
3. The suggestion won't cease to exist.

---

1. How do I remove this specific suggestion?
2. Is this a bug or wanted behavior?

---

[image]
[image: Settings1]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

- Clear your entire form and search history. (This will obviously affect other search items too).
  [image]

### Solution 2

- Remove the specific entry in the `formhistory.sqlite` database. It can be found in your [firefox profile directory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).
  [image: database_tables]
  [image: database_entries]